# How to Launch Spotlight from the Terminal

Tags: macos, osx-snow-leopard, terminal, spotlight

I used [this tip](http://lifehacker.com/5280456/hide-your-mac-menu-bar-and-dock-for-a-cleaner-desktop) top hide my menu bar in a bunch of applications, which is a great way to get more free screen space.  The one downside is that (for inexplicable reasons) it disables Spotlight when I'm in those applications--e.g. even if I hover over the menu bar to make it appear, clicking on the Spotlight icon does nothing.

I have a plan to work around this: I'd like to launch Spotlight using QuicKeys, which lets you run terminal commands using keyboard shortcuts.  But to do that, I need to know how to launch Spotlight with a terminal command.  Does anyone know how to do this?

I'm on OS X 10.6.

Comment: The official keyboard command for Spotlight is Cmd+Space. Does that work with the menu hiding script?

Comment: No, unfortunately it doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the command-line program `mdfind` as a complete substitution for the Spotlight GUI. Accessing results is a bit inconvenient, though.

---

You can, using a little GUI scripting, open a `Finder` window, and perform a Spotlight search there.

For this to work, you need support for assistive devices in *System Preferences » Universal Access* and *Full Keyboard Access* in *System Preferences » Keyboard » Keyboard Shortcuts*.

Open `/Applications/Utilities/AppleScript Editor.app`, and enter the following script:

```
on run argv # we expect program arguments
    tell application "Finder"
        activate # focus Finder
        tell application "System Events"
            keystroke "f" using command down # press Cmd-F
            keystroke (item 1 of argv) # enter the program argument into search box
            key code 36 # press enter
            key code 48 # press tab
            keystroke " " # press space
        end tell
    end tell
end run
```

<sup>The steps "press tab" and "press space" are only necessary if you have *not* specified *Search This Mac* in *Finder » Preferences » Advanced* -- then we tab&select the *This Mac* option in the Finder search window.</sup>

Now save as Script, and execute from Terminal like this:

```
osascript spotlight.scpt test
```

What happens then looks somewhat like this:

[image]

---

<sub>The "Spotlight" action for Automator is probably not a good idea, since it runs until all results are available. Combined with *Reveal Finder Items* is a great way to see what opening 10,000 Finder windows looks like.</sub>

---

Other options, as always, are using applications such as [LaunchBar](http://www.obdev.at/products/launchbar/index.html), [Alfred](http://www.alfredapp.com/) or [Butler](http://manytricks.com/butler/) to initiate Spotlight search or provide an alternative UI.

Comment: with keystroke (item 1 of argv) I get error "execution error: Can’t get item 1 of {}."

Answer (score 0):

From the [Spotlight manual](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#DOCUMENTATION/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/10.5/man8/Spotlight.8.html) :

> There are no configurations to Spotlight, and **users should not run manually**.

Guess that explains it all.

Comment: It refers to the Spotlight GUI process. Not Spotlight more broadly. There is e.g. the `mdfind` command-line application.

Comment: And the author asks for the Spotlight "GUI"